# How to select for update one row from table A and all joined rows from table B in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, select-for-update

I have a table that is a queue of tasks with each task requiring exclusive access to several resources. I want my query to select a single task that doesn't need resources claimed by other similar sessions.

If each task had to work on a single resource I would've written something like this:

```
select *
from tasks t
inner join resources r
on r.id = t.resource_id
order by t.submitted_ts
limit 1
for update skip locked
```

But since I have multiple resources I somehow have to lock them all:

```
select *
from tasks t
inner join task_details td
on t.id = td.task_id
inner join resources r
on r.id = td.resource_id
order by t.submitted_ts, t.id
limit ???
for update skip locked
```

I cannot limit by 1, since I need to lock all joined rows of `resources`.

It also seems to me that I should try and lock *all* rows of `resources`, so it must be not `skip locked`, but `nowait` for resources and `skip locked` for `tasks`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I had to create a helper function that either locks all linked rows or not:

```
create or replace function try_lock_resources(p_task_id bigint)
returns boolean
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    perform *
    from task_details td
    join resources r
    on td.resource_id = r.resource_id
    where td.task_id = p_task_id 
    for update of r nowait;

    return true;
exception when lock_not_available then
    return false;
end;
$$;
```

Then I needed to invoke this function for each row:

```
select *
from tasks
where processing_status = 'Unprocessed'
and try_lock_resources(task_id)
order by created_ts
limit 1
for update skip locked
```

After this query is run, only the returned row and its associated resources are locked. I verified that an identical query from another session returns the first unprocessed tasks that has no resources in common with the one returned by the first session.

P.S.: the original answer used a different query (which you shouldn't use as is):

```
with unprocessed_tasks as materialized (
    select * 
    from tasks t
    where processing_status = 'Unprocessed'
    order by created_ts
)
select *
from unprocessed_tasks
where try_lock_resources(task_id)
limit 1
for update skip locked
```

The problem with this query is that the following could (and did happen):

- session A runs the query, locks task X and starts working on it
- session B starts running the query, the materialized CTE is run first, returning task X among other tasks
- session A commits the transaction and releases all locks
- session B finishes running the query, locks task X and starts working on it

Answer (score -1):

LIMIT clause applies to joined table.

Instead of table A use subquery with it's own LIMIT.

```sql
SELECT
  "table a"."учебный год",
  "table b".семестр
FROM
  (SELECT
      "Учебный год"."учебный год"
    FROM
      "Учебный год"
    ORDER BY
      "Учебный год"."учебный год"
    LIMIT 1) "table a"
  INNER JOIN "Семестр" "table b" ON "table b"."учебный год" = "table a"."учебный год"
```

Comment: You example is 1:M, while resources and tasks are M:N

Comment: The question is "How to select for update **one row** from table A"

Comment: Yes, one row for which all other rows in the other table can be locked as well. Your example selects one row first, without checking if `semester`s are available. The can work only because each `year` has its own set of `semester`s.